# What is the difference between "keep on challenging" and "keep challenging"?

Tags: differences

As I listened to the English radio, the DJ said "keep on challenging yourself". But I have known that we can also say that "keep challenging yourself". What is the role of "on" in the former expression?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Since it's a DJ -- this may be related to "Keep on keepin' on."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two sentances have the same meaning. "On" in the first sentence is just a preposition.Essentially the first sentence is teling you to continue to be engged in challenging yourself, while the sencond sentence is telling you to continue to challenge yourself.