# Difference between Keep on+V-ing and Keep+V-ing

Tags: verbs, differences, phrasal-verbs

Please help me to find out the answer. Am I right if I say

> I **keep on walking** in this dark way?

or

> I **keep walking** in this dark way?

What is the difference between the two sentences?

Comment: Purely my opinion, but I get the sense that "keep" is more tone-neutral than "keep on."

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between "keep on challenging" and "keep challenging"?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/267984/what-is-the-difference-between-keep-on-challenging-and-keep-challenging)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"to keep doing" is just the shortened form of the older "to keep on doing".
There is no difference in meaning. Very often we have the phenomenon that prepositions are dropped in verb constructions.

I would guess that the shortened form "to keep doing" is used more frequently today than the longer version. I think it is a general rule that when speakers have agreed on a shortened form then it is the shortened form that is used and not the older, longer one.

Comment: +1 But even though *keep doing* seems to have been around for two-hundred years, I still hear a lot of *keep on doing*.

Answer (score 1):

**OED meaning 40(b) of the verb *to keep* has examples from 1800:**

> > a. To continue, persevere, go on (in a specified course or action). 
> >     b. With pres. pple. as compl.
> >
> > Examples:
> >
> > 1800   W. Gifford Baviad (ed. 6) 27 (note)    Some contemptible
> >     vulgarity, such as ‘That's your sort!’..‘What's to pay?’ ‘Keep
> >     moving’, &c.
>
> 1806   J. Beresford Miseries Human Life I. vi. 131   The
>   Monster..keeps braying away.
>
> 1858   N. Hawthorne Fr. & Ital. Jrnls. I. 124   Niagara..keeps pouring
>   on forever and ever.
>
> 1890   T. F. Tout Hist. Eng. from 1689 134   He kept changing his
>   plans.
>
> 1892   Temple Bar Feb. 198   She kept tumbling off her horse.

**However sense 3 of the composite verb *keep on* means almost exactly the same thing, but with entries from 1589:**

Examples:

> 3. intr. To continue or persist in a course or action; to go on with something. Now freq. with pres. pple.>
>
> > 1589   G. Puttenham Arte Eng. Poesie ii. iii. 57   In this maner doth
> >     the Greeke dactilus begin slowly and keepe on swifter till th' end.
> >
> > a1616   Shakespeare Othello (1623) iii. iii. 458   The Ponticke Sea,
> >     Whose Icie Current..keepes due on To the Proponticke.
> >
> > 1720   D. Defoe Mem. Cavalier 255   We kept on all Night.
> >
> > 1856   Titan Mag. Dec. 516/1   ‘We shall never come across each other
> >     again’, she kept on saying to herself.
> >
> > 1889   A. Conan Doyle Micah Clarke xxii. 224   Strike quick, strike
> >     hard, and keep on striking.

**The only difference, therefore would seem that *keep on* when used in this sense is an older form with examples from the 16th century. The bare *keep* meaning *to persist in a course of action* does not begin to appear until the 19th century**